# Use the same error handler in different modules in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, http-status-code-404, zend-framework-modules

I have many modules in an Zend application. There will be errors and exceptions in every module, right? So I create the error page in the Application module, and it works.

However, in other modules, they can't use the error page. So what should I do to reuse the error page?

Here's the `module.config.php` file in Application module:

```
return array(
    ...,
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

The problem occurs when I return a HTTP 404 response manually with following code:

```
if ( $information == null ) {
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(404);
    return $response;
}
```

However, when I access an illegal resources like http://example.com/something-do-not-exist. I will reach the 404 error page with the exception `The requested URL could not be matched by routing.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration you have listed is *defined* in the application module, however it is **not** specific to that module.

This is because during the application bootstrap each `module.config.php` is [merged together into one configuration array (using `array_merge_recursive()`)](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/config.advanced.html). This is the configuration you can get using `$serviceManager->get('Config');`

So the configuration is global to the application and all errors (exceptions) should use the same error template (`application/view/error/index.phtml`).

Keep in mind however that the loading order of the modules is important; as modules loading last will always overwrite existing configuration.

Comment: You mean I should add `$serviceManager->get('Config');` to the Module.php in other modules?

Comment: @HowardXie No, that is how you fetch the merged application config. If you need the **same** error template in all modules then there should be nothing else you need to do - the code you have posted should work for all modules.

Comment: Of course not. If I use the config above, I should create error pages in each module. Because the relative path `/../view/error/404.phtml` not exists in other modules.

Comment: You only need the `not_found_template` or `exception_template` configuration in **one** module and that will be used throughout the application - just omit those settings for any other module.

Comment: However, I gave an 404 response in another module, and the error page doesn't show. I got a blank page on the screen. Why? (`$response = $this->getResponse(); $response->setStatusCode(404);return $response;`)

Comment: Actually, when I access a resource that doesn't exists, I will get the error page. However, if I return a 404-response manually, I will get an blank page.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by following code:

```
if ( $information == null ) {
    return $this->notFoundAction();
}
```

And this will redirect you to the global error page.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't other modules use the error page ?

Anyway, there's more than one way to do it ;)

You can for example define multiple names in your template_map for each error page you want.